# How to make object reactive after mounting?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a component that, after mounting (cannot be done before mounting), interacts with a service to create and then receive a non-reactive object. Any ideas how to make this object reactive?

A google search and vue documentation search has left me empty handed.

```
@Component
export default class Curve extends Vue {

  chunks: Chunk<string>;

  async mounted(){ 
    let service = new ChunkManager<string>(interval, this.sampler, etc...);
    this.chunks = this.manager._chunk;
 };
};
```

And the chunk class:

```
export class Chunk<T>{
    id = 'testID';
    constructor(){};
    valid = false;
    toRender: T;
};
```

**Answer:**

Credit to Macintosh_89. This is a formatted answer demonstrating that setting a property to null allows it to become reactive even if it is set to a non-reactive object.

```
@Component
export default class Curve extends Vue {

  chunk1 = null; 
  chunk2 = undefined;

  async mounted(){ 

     this.$watch('chunk1', () => console.log('chunk1 changed'),
           {immediate: false, deep: true});
     this.$watch('chunk2', () => console.log('chunk2 changed'),
           {immediate: false, deep: true});

     let exampleObj = = {
        name: 'bob',
        age: 111
     };

     this.chunk1 = bob;
     this.chunk2 = bob;
     console.log(chunk1, chunk2);
  };
};
```

Comment: any code would be helpful. Do you have code?

Comment: @Macintosh_89 Added cut down code.

Comment: Not sure if i understood  correctly and i don't know typescript,  how would this object will update ? after making a service call. For making it reactive it needs to change/update. you could bind changing object property in `computed` or `watch`

Comment: Object will be routinely updated by the ChunkManager class. How would you bind the object after the instance is initialised?

Comment: You can set `watch` for that object. You could watch on say `reactiveChunk`  which returns  object from chunkManager class .  so on your template you will call `reactiveChunk` as property. Whenever your object updates  `reactiveChunk` will be updated

Comment: I'm not following sorry, call it as a property? Maybe you could make a code example in an answer? Can be a javascript example if you're not comfortable with typescript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202814/discussion-between-mj-wales-and-macintosh-89).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For formatted typescript example see original question.

```
                          .........................
```

OK I will try my best . Perhaps this is what you are looking for. I don't know how your object is getting updated. I am assuming this is how it may work.  Please Excuse the formatting

```
  <template>
    <div>{{ reactiveChunk }} </div>  
    </template>    

   data :() => ({
            chunks:null
              }),
   mounted ():{
             this.serviceCall() // from methods
               }
   watch:{
            reactiveChunk: function(){
            return this.chunks //assuming this gets updated routinely
           },
   method:{
             serviceCall :function() {
             let data = servicecall_to_API(params)
             this.chunks = data  
         }
```

Comment: This works, really surprised but it seems to work great.

Comment: @MJ_Wales Glad to know, i had same issue , `watch` and  `computed` does the trick